# Standing wave equation

Tags: waves

**A question about standing wave equation.**

We send a harmonic wave that travels down a rope that is fixed at the end with the equation(like in the picture):

$$y = A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$

[image]

The wave that travels down a rope gets reflected at the rope’s end and has the equation:

$$ y = A \sin[k(2l-x) - \omega t + π]$$ where $l$ is the length of the rope.

I don't understand this equation. We add $π$ because the waves get inverted when it is reflected, but I don't understand where the $(2l-x)$ part comes from.

Comment: You need to define $x$. Is it a position relative to some origin or is it a distance travelled?

Answer (score 3):

In this problem, fixed end is at $x = l$. Corresponding boundary condition has a form
$$
y(x = l, t) = 0.
$$
Solutions to the wave equation with this boundary condition have the following form
$$
y(x,t) = f(kx-\omega t) - f(k(2l-x)-\omega t). \quad (1)
$$
In this problem, $f(kx-\omega t) = A\sin(kx-\omega t)$. For $t$ large enough, in the $x<l$ area, only the second term in (1) is nonzero and you have reflected wave packet
$$
y(x,t) = -A\sin(k(2l-x)-\omega t) = A\sin(k(2l-x)-\omega t +\pi).
$$